# roots of polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

How to find the roots of $x^5-2^5$ by hand. I see that we get a root of $x=2$ and 4 complex roots (should come in pairs). Not sure how to work out the complex roots. Do we need to convert to polar? Would that make it easier to see the other roots?

Comment: What if you write $x^5 = 2^5$ and take the fifth root of each side? Clear

Comment: For this kind of polynomial, the roots are indeed easier to see in polar form.

Comment: @Amzoti: Which fifth root?

Comment: They are $2$ and the fifth roots of unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as $x^5 - 2^5e^{2\pi ik} = 0$

So your solutions are $x = 2{e^{2\pi ik/5}}$ for $k=-2,-1,0,1,2$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, polar form would make it easier to see the other roots. Write $x=re^{i\theta},$ so that you're solving $$r^5e^{5i\theta}=2^5.$$ It's easy enough to find $r$ simply by taking the modulus, and if you know a few basic properties of the complex exponential function, you can find values of $\theta$ that give you all five solutions.